# How to configure Dynacache CacheProvider?

Tags: caching, websphere

I'm trying to implement a Dynacache CacheProvider and having problems. Here is what I've done:

- I've got my Dynacache CacheProvider implementation jar under D:\IBM\WebSphere85\AppServer\lib
- I have com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheConfig.cacheProviderName configured as JVM custom property with the correct CacheProvider implementation class.
- Created cacheinstance.properties located under D:\IBM\WebSphere85\AppServer\properties with the relevant settings including the com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheConfig.cacheProviderName right class name value.
- I have the cacheinstance.properties also part of the Dynacache CacheProvider implementation jar.
- I have the Object cache Instance configured to have a new dyna cache. This also have the com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheConfig.cacheProviderName as a custom system property.
- My application using the following to access the cache:

code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();                               
props.put("com.ibm.ws.cache.CacheConfig.cacheProviderName","com.myCacheProvider");
map = (DistributedObjectCache)DistributedObjectCacheFactory.getMap("mycache",props);
```

I'm getting the following when the application trying to access DynaCache:

```
[9/18/12 10:10:52:917 EDT] 00000050 ServerCache   E   DYNA1066E: Unable to initialize the cache provider "com.myCacheProvider". The Dynamic cache will be used to create the cache instance "default" instead of the configured cache provider.
[9/18/12 10:10:52:919 EDT] 00000050 ServerCache   E   ENGLISH ONLY MESSAGE: cacheProvider is null. Check for the cache provider libraries 
[9/18/12 10:10:52:920 EDT] 00000050 ServerCache   I   DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named default initialized successfully.
```

I'm using WAS 8.5.

Any ideas what is going on and how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Guy,

I would turn on Dyna cache trace to see why this error occurs

Trace String:
com.ibm.ws.cache.*=all:com.ibm.ws.drs.*=all

This should give us clues on what is happening and depending on what we see from the trace would provide us info on what to do next.

HTH